# How to create a gradient texture?

Tags: edit-mode, image

I am wondering how to recreate some kinds of effects (you can easily do in Photoshop) in Blender.

I want to create the gradient textures like ones pictured below, should I render objects and blur them in compositor? Or can I achieve it using only material nodes?

[image: Radial gradient]

[image: Linear gradient]

Comment: The vertical one might be doable with the *Color Ramp* node

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can acheive this with Cycles material nodes using the 'Gradient Texture' node.

[image]

Setting the gradient node to 'Quadratic sphere' (and with a little offset from the vector mapping node) restults in this (on a plane with uv basic unwrapping):

[image]

To control the scale of the 'Quadratic sphere' in the result above I scaled the UV's as scaling using the vector mapping node node seemed to scale it towards the corner.

For a linear gradient you can simply set the Gradient Texture to 'Linear':

[image]

[image]

For different colours you can simply use a colour 'MixRBG' node and use the *factor* of the gradient texture instead of the *colour* and connect it to the 'Fac' of the mix node.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ray. Now I don't need the Photoshop any more ;).

Comment: You can also use the "color ramp" node instead of the "mix" node. It allows more settings and finesse. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OIO5P.jpg

Comment: @Zampai this is a better answer than the accepted one IMHO