# multiple texture in a Single material

Tags: texturing, shaders

I want to use two texture in one object(curtain), upper part of it will be designed texture and bottom part to be solid color or different texture .People said to use baked texture or color different map.But same time I need to change the tile or transparency.Please give me some solution.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34837/2217), but instead of using different BSFD shaders, just use two diffuse, one with your texture, and the other with just the solid color.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this procedurally by using the generated vector like this:

[image]

The Blue channel mean the Z coordinates,and by increasing the contrast you can get your mask,and you can still edit the texture without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

i created an image that was 1/3 black and 2/3 transparent (shown in the last image). this is how i cut the material in half. i made my two materials in the node editor and connected them with a mix shader. i used the alpha channel of the split image as the factor of the mix shader. this makes it so where it is black in the image it shows one material and where it is transparent it shows the other.

[image]

[image]

[image]

if you need more help on how to get to this point please ask me questions on specifically what you need. thanks -Tainin

Answer (score 1):

Same as Omar, but with a separate x/y/z instead of r/g/b (it usually makes more sense but is the same for blender), using 2 UVs so that you can adjust size and translate each texture independently (or use a solid color) and using a constant interpolation in the ColorRamp (only one stop to move, and sharp transition).

[image]

Instead of mixing colors you could mix different shaders (like satin on the top and velvet on the bottom)