# Smooth transition between two materials

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I need to make the transition smoother between the 2 different colored objects in my scene, somehow like one of the colors fades into the other one, while still keeping the line between them.

[image]

Comment: what render engine are you using?

Comment: Use the Gradient and Color Ramp nodes (in Cycles) and use it as a factor for a Mix Shader of two materials. Please see related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture-from-one-material-to-another-opaque-to-clear

Comment: Here's related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials (though it shows how to do it in Cycles). Judging from your render I assume you want to do it in Blender Internal Render right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In ***Blender Render*** engine you may achieve it using the ***material nodes***.
[image]

Being in *Edit Mode* unwrap your mesh (press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Project From View*).
[image]

Create some materials- basic *Orange* and *Pink* materials (the ones you want to blend), *Transition* (this material'll be used for blending the ones above using ***material nodes***) and *Gradient* (this'll be used to create a gradient texture for blending materials).
[image]

With *Gradient* material selected go to the *Texture* header, set the texture type to ***Blend***, check the *Ramp* checkbox in *Colors* panel, then press the *Linear* and *Vertical* buttons in *Blend* panel. Also set the *Mapping* coordinates to ***UV***. Your gradient texture is now ready.
[image]

Now select the *Transition* material and press ***Use Shader Nodes*** button.
[image]

Go to ***Node Editor*** and set up nodes as pictured below. First add two *Material* nodes- the *Orange* one and *Pink* one (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Input*-->*Material*) and mix it using *MixRGB* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Color*-->*MixRGB*). Use the *Texture* node (previously created *Gradient* texture) as a factor for blending. Plug in the ***UV*** output of the *Geometry* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Input*-->*Geometry*) to the ***Vector*** input of the *Texture* node as shown below.
[image]

Now you may manipulate the transition between materials (go to the *Texture* header of the *Gradient* material and play with the sliders in *Colors* panel for different results).
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might also be possible to skip the ramp and scale the UV coordinates.  You would have to make sure the texture is clamped instead of repeating (although that is checked by default).

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :). Could you mark this answer as accepted?
Thanks!