# how to blend or diffuse two materials properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

As you can see in the image that I've attached, there are two materials used for the soil and the grassland. please be kind enough to tell me, how to make the boundary looks better ? how to make a proper diffusion or a realistic gradient between these two ? 
Im so sorry if this is a dumb question, but im new to blender.
-peace-

[image]

Comment: This has been asked before frequently https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials/ also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh/748#748

Comment: No need to apologise for a dumb question - there is nothing dumb about the question itself, however this is a very frequent question and it is extremely easy to find the answer just by searching this website. Some reasearch is allways a good idea before asking.

Comment: There is a point here though....  rather than a gradient, there might be a call for treatment of the edges where grass is churned up, and there's an abrupt change of texture between cultivated and uncultivated ground. Displacement? Dynamic Paint if animated?