# Mix two Shader together

Tags: uv, shaders, weight-painting

Hey Guys I' am struggling the whole time how I can mix a second shader to the place where the marshmallow swimming. When I take a second uv, the texture will have a square circle around the marshmallow..
Is there a method to draw a weight paint and make this as a uv?
[image]

Comment: You can do regular Texture painting and then use that as the factor in a Mix node. Make sure you are using your new UV in a UV input node.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you smooth the edge between two materials?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials)