# How do I enable texture preview in the node editor?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes

[image: Preview]

I'm following another answered question on stackexchange and one of the screencaptures demonstrated
the node editor with texture previews on individual nodes including output. This is from a much older version of Blender so I don't know if this feature was removed or is just disabled somewhere in the settings. How do I enable it back if it's just disabled?

UPDATE: It would also really help if I could get newer example of this tutorial as it's very outdated [Smooth transition between two materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-two-materials#49921).

Comment: It's a paid-for addon available [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview/?ref=110).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previews like that are a feature in the *Texture node editor* and the *Compositor*, but not the *Shader Editor*.

[image]

Using the *Texture Node Editor* for this task is honestly not very ideal, easiest way to achieve a smooth gradient between materials would be somehow like this:

[image]

You could use the *Node wrangler* add-on to view a single shader on your object, by Ctrl+Shift+Left clicking on them.
Alternatively, there's a paid add-on called [Node Preview](https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview) which gives a similar type of preview to the *Texture Node Editor* and *Compositor*.

Comment: Note that the preview feature is expected to be in 3.0

Comment: That's really nice, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: warning that paid addon relies on external libraries to work, and as far as I've heard, does not work at all under Windows 10 or 11 since the MSVC runtimes' libraries are not the same versions as what the addon expects (possibly work around by manually getting the libraries and putting them in, but that was just way too much work imo for a feature that should exist in blender).

...still wonder why devs make us go out of our way to figure out what the texture at that point should look like and assume we can just wing it :( :( :(