# How to blend(gradient effect) two different 3D materials, in cycles blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

How to create a gradient texture from two different 3D materials, for example this post:

([How to create a gradient texture from one material to another (opaque to clear)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture-from-one-material-to-another-opaque-to-clear))
 shows how to do this exactly but WITHOUT a 3D texture, my question is how to do this with a 3D texture, where each of the two textures has a different normal map, how would you combine them using a gradient(or fade or merging effect) of two different 3D textures, is this even possible?

I ask this because I'm trying to make a beach using two different textures with each there own different bump map and normal map, here is an example of what i have thus far:
[image: Beach texture fade without bump maps/normal maps]

Answer (score 4):

### Final result:

[image: Final]

### Overview:

You can use **Gradient Texture** as a mask for your textures.

Prepare you textures as usual with needed normals/bumps and mix them trough **Gradient Texture** or which ever you need.

[image: nodes]

### Edit:

If you are using **Image Textures** don't forget you need proper **Texture Coordinates** no matter if they are form **UV mapping** or using **Generated/Object** texture space.

### Blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but must admit, quite a noob, i tried the above, and the bump maps worked, but no color textures appeared, perhaps if i show you the node setup i have:

Comment: okay, just noticed your comments! give me a sec...