# How can I have a smooth transition between colors on a low poly model?

Tags: materials

I don't know what to call it but I have a low poly landscape right here, but my problem is its color.

[image]

I want it to have like some sort of gradient effect using different materials. If you don't understand, take a look at the islands in this picture.

[image]

It has a kind of gradienty thing with the islands. Basically the transformation of the color from green and brown on this color is seamless, and I don't want a sudden change of color in mine. I know it's impossible to make it follow my landscape with just one material, but I just wanna see if there's a simpler method like using random on object index or a color ramp, and I really don't wanna make this manually.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Low+poly+water&tab=votes

Comment: To clarify, you want this transition for different materials or colours? Material is not equal term to colour.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials

Comment: @LukeD I want the transition for different materials.. gah I don't know how to explain it in words. :/

Comment: Here you go: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77274/how-to-blendgradient-effect-two-different-3d-materials-in-cycles-blender/77282#77282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient texture can do that. If you want to change the gradient orientation, go through a Mapping node first.

[image]

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it answers your question