# How to smooth out the edge of a material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Hello Blender Stack Exchange !

I'm having a bit of an issu on a personal project right now, and that issue is that I can't seem to "blur out" or "fade" a material on a part of a mesh how I want to.
Here's a pic of the situation :

[image: Image of the problem]

I'd like for the gold material to fade on the edge to the silver color, but I do not know of an efficient way of doing so... please help.

Thanks in advance ! :)

Here's a link to the file : [GoogleDrive share link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PVImCXQePQQF8dgCDZc-XPMsTcHjW8Zk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This topic was just covered on the Blender Nation site: [Procedural Texture Blurring](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/04/10/procedural-texture-blurring/)

Comment: You'll need the same material, so you can just copy the gold and silver and make a gradient version. Then mix the two shaders with a mix shader node where the factor is a texture of some sort, e.g., a black and white gradient.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/77274/28015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply any 0-1 gradient as 'Fac', either to mix colors, or to mix shaders.

Here, shaders are mixed with the  provided procedural 'Gradient' texture node, but you could paint your own, or whatever you like. The'Mapping' node controls position and orientation, The 'Color Ramp' node controls the transition.

[image]

[image]