# How do I degrade a texture with the edge of a model?

Tags: texturing, edges, texture-painting

[image]I know I have not explained well, but I leave a picture made in Photoshop to see what I mean. I'm new using blender, it's for a video game.[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials

Comment: And here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77274/how-to-blendgradient-effect-two-different-3d-materials-in-cycles-blender/77282#77282