# Transition between 2 terrain texture

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting

I have terrain (floating island) with 2 textures on it. Bottom (stone) and top (grass)

[image]

As you can see on picture there is not transition from stone to grass so my question is how i can make it. Here is my node setting:

[image]

I have looked at [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials) question but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have tried with WaveTexture and ColorRamp but this is result i get with node settings:

[image]

[image]

I have ALMOST got effect i wanted but still it is not good enough because if i have transition on not flat surface i do not know how to do it.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77274/how-to-blendgradient-effect-two-different-3d-materials-in-cycles-blender

Comment: @cegaton Please look at edit