# What can I do to blend the transition between 2 materials in specific parts of a mesh in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I need to blend or smooth the transition between theese materials on my charecter:

[image: ![I need to mix the 2 materials but only where the dark blue hits the light blue]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWWwm.png)
I need to mix the 2 materials but only where the dark blue hits the light blue[image: I need it to smooth, blend or anything that does not make it look so bad hahaha]
I need it to smooth, blend or anything that does not make it look so bad hahaha

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34834/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture-from-one-material-to-another-opaque-to-clear and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77274/how-to-blendgradient-effect-two-different-3d-materials-in-cycles-blender

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single material with both your material setups connected to a mix shader node, and then use:
a. a texture for your model, made with the texture painter after you've unwrapped your model
b. use the vertex colours, set the brush to black or white and paint where you want your materials to be.
and connect either of those to the factor of your mix shader