# How make UV Textured mesh with material instead of specific colour?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, masking

Just trying to replicate table with epoxy. But can't figure out how to create a complex material.
I have a textured table top but can't replace black strip with a material.[image]

Eventually, I wanna get something like this:
[image]

But when I am using mix shader it turns blue:

[image]
[image]

I understand there should be some mask but can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91709/what-can-i-do-to-blend-the-transition-between-2-materials-in-specific-parts-of-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figure it out. Need to add RGB BW and do some math rules, but would be glad if someone will present more correct or convenient way of doing that
[image]

Comment: why don't you make 2 materials, one for the wood, one for the epoxy? or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, what I wanna do is to apply two materials on one object at specific places. Due to tabletop is quite high poly it's gonna be inconvenient to apply them using faces.  So I decided I to paint a texture and apply material on places where texture is missing.