# How To Make a Radial Gradient Sky in Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using Blender Internal. I am trying to achieve a sky like link in the  following picture, but I could only make a Linear Gradient.

[image: picture of desired sky]

Comment: Here is related answer, that may be helpful for you if you want to create the same gradient type texture in Cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it using ***Blend*** texture with the ***Quadratic Sphere*** (or ***Spherical***) progression type.
[image]

In *World* header set its type to ***Real Sky***.
[image]

Then go to *Texture* header and set the texture type to ***World***. Add a new texture and set it as ***Blend***.
[image]

In *Colors* panel check the ***Ramp*** checkbox and set the colors transition using sliders. Set the colors interpolation type to ***Ease*** also. In *Blend* panel set the progression type to ***Quadratic Sphere*** (or ***Spherical***). In *Mapping* panel set the coordinates type to ***AngMap***. Experiment with settings below. Check the ***Horizon*** box in *Influence* panel also.
[image]

You may also try to set the colors interpolation type to ***B-Spline*** and add some sliders with slighty different hue to have a better control over colors transition.
[image]