# making two colors in one object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, color

I am trying to model a grass stalk and I want the bottom part to be brownish-yellow and the top part to be fresh-green. All I know is that we have to select regions from the mesh and assign different colors to them, but this method will not make it realistic. It will look odd. I want those two colors to merge in the middle. I think you know what I mean.

I want it like this: you can see the different colors and they are merging in the middle:

[image]

Comment: Nevermind. I found the solution. :D https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture

Comment: Also helpful: [How to create a gradient texture from one material to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34834/2217)

Answer (score 1):

you can use vertex colors, or a blend texture or just use a bitmap gradient you should be able to look all of those up on youtube..sorry this is not a very specific answer, but if you look those up on youtube you will see how many options you have and which one suits your needs and skill set the best to cover each one would take far to much typing here.