# Blender 2.8 - quadratic gradient fail

Tags: materials, node-editor

My goal is to create a gradient in a circular manner (one color in the center of the circle, the other at the edge with a transition in between).

I attempted to apply the lessons from [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22929/how-to-create-a-gradient-texture), but can't get it to work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does your sphere/disk have UVs?

Also, if you have UVs and move them by x-0.5, y-0.5, the gradient gets pushed outside of the UV space. If it's there it might be very faint.

An easy setup to control this can be the following:

[image: Nodes]

Note the Empty in the Texture Coordinate Node! - You can move, rotate and scale it to position the gradient. Keep it in the center of your object as a starting point. (My mapping node looks different because I'm using a build of 2.81 at the moment. But it works the same way.)

Another tip: Use the NodeWrangler Addon that comes bundled with Blender to look at the Outputs of the Texture Coordinates or the Mapping Node while you make changes. (Just Ctrl + Click the Node a few times) That way you can see what you're affecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Quadratic Sphere** and not **Quadratic** in the *Gradient Texture* node.